# How to install ros2 packages on Windows 10?

Tags: ros, ros2, packages, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have a lot of experience working with ros1 on ubuntu (specifically melodic), and all of the packages and ros itself was downloaded via apt package manager.

I was wondering if there was something like that on Windows 10?

Starting with downloading and installing ROS 2 itself, you still must download a bunch of dependencies manually. Then, I believe chocolatey is used in some sense.

But how do you download packages like in ROS 1 on Ubuntu? For instance, what's the equivalent to something like:
`sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop` and `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-octomap`

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339630/how-to-install-ros2-packages-on-windows-10?/) by [zipp39](https://answers.ros.org/users/44576/zipp39/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Windows does not have a package manager like Ubuntu. As such the installation instructions are not as simple for installing dependencies as you've noticed. However we do build binaries that you can unzip to install.

Documentation is here: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Windows-Install-Binary/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0